# How to highlight and auto perform click on recently added item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have two scenario so first one is I want to highlight and auto perform click on only recently added item in RecyclerView and second one is if user select or click on any of the item that time also that should be highlighted and clickable so this second scenario I have already implemented but I don't know how to highlight and do auto perform click on last added item on the list.

MyAdapterClass

```
class CarItemAdapter(
        private val activity: MainActivity,
        private val carList: ArrayList<MyEntity>,
        private val myViewModel: MyViewModel,
        private val settings: Settings
) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    var listener: OnItemsClickListener? = null
    var rowIndex = 0

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return when (viewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_ADDITEM -> ViewHolderAddCarItem(SettingsCarAddItemTileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false))
            VIEW_TYPE_ITEM -> ViewHolderCarItem(SettingsCarItemTileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false))
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolderCarItem -> holder.bind(carList[position -1], position-1)
            is ViewHolderAddCarItem -> holder.bind()
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolderAddCarItem internal constructor(private var binding: SettingsCarAddItemTileBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind() {
            binding.lifecycleOwner = activity
            binding.handler = EventHandler()
            binding.userSpecificCarSubtitle.setText(R.string.user_specific_car_subtitle)
        }

        inner class EventHandler {
            fun onItemClicked() {
                activity.showSubPage(AddVehiclePage(activity), true)
            }
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolderCarItem internal constructor(private var binding: SettingsCarItemTileBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(myEntity: MyEntity, position: Int) {

            binding.lifecycleOwner = activity
            val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myEntity.image, 0, Objects.requireNonNull<ByteArray>(myEntity.image).size)
            binding.carImage.setImageBitmap(bmp)
            binding.carName.text = myEntity.label

            binding.layoutCar.setOnClickListener {
                listener?.onItemClick(myEntity)
                settings.carNumber = myEntity.carNumber
                settings.selectedCarType = activity.getString(R.string.settings_category_view_sub_title_for_user_specific_car)
                settings.isCarSelected = true
                rowIndex = position
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            binding.deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { bbdCarViewModel.deleteByFinNumber(myEntity.carNumber) }
                settings.isBBDCarSelected = false
                carList.removeAt(position)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            if (rowIndex == position) {
                binding.layoutCar.setBackgroundColor(activity.getColor(R.color.petrol))
                binding.carName.setTextColor(activity.getColor(R.color.white))
            } else {
                binding.layoutCar.setBackgroundColor(activity.getColor(R.color.coolGray))
                binding.carName.setTextColor(activity.getColor(R.color.coolGray_80k))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == 0 && position <= carList.size) {
            VIEW_TYPE_ADDITEM
        } else VIEW_TYPE_ITEM
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return carList.size + 1
    }

    interface OnItemsClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(myEntity: MyEntity)
    }

    fun setWhenClickListener(listener: OnItemsClickListener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    companion object {
        const val VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0
        const val VIEW_TYPE_ADDITEM = 1
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Check if( carList. size()-1 == position ), then you catch last added item on the list.

Comment: yes doing the same but in this way my last two item getting highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

We can add placeholder to adapter class and store highlighted items in it by unique id. Then in bind function we could highlight items which have those ids:

### **1. Add a placeholder**

We can handle active states with having a **placeholder** to hold highlighted items.

It could be a HashSet , the type of Long is for item id's which we'll set as stable in init block.

```kotlin
class CarItemAdapter(...) : ... {
...
val activeHolder: HashSet<Long> = HashSet()
    
init {
    // Represents each item in the data set with a unique indentifier
    setHasStableIds(true)
 }
...
```

---

### **2. Add recently added item to placeHolder**

Now we've got a unique identifier for each item, and a place holder for
holding the active states for highlighted items.

We want last added item be highlighted, so let's assume you're adding the new item in EventHandler's onclick method, update the mothed as below:

```kotlin
inner class EventHandler {
            fun onItemClicked() {
                with(activeHolder){                  
                    val lastItemId = getItemId(carList.size - 1)
                    // Remove last item's id from our holder to prevent last two items being highlighted.
                    if (contains(lastItemId)) remove(lastItemId) 
                    // Suppose we add new item to carList here
                    carList.add(newItem)
                    // add last item id of new list to the holder   
                    add(getItemId(carList.size - 1))   
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged()
                
            }
        }
```

In code above I we supposed that adding new Item to list is inside `carList.add(newItem)` , if this is not the case, wrap the with(){} block of code above around the `carList.add(newCar)`.

---

### **3. Add and Remove items to placeholder by onClick action**

Pretty straightforward this one, just a oneliner:

```kotlin
binding.layoutCar.setOnClickListener {
    ...
    with(activeHolder) { if (contains(itemId)) remove(itemId) else add(itemId) }
    ...
notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

### **4. Finale; perform highlighting**

```kotlin
    inner class ViewHolderCarItem internal constructor(private var binding: SettingsCarItemTileBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(myEntity: MyEntity, position: Int) {
            ...

            binding.layoutCar.setOnClickListener {
                ...
                with(activeHolder) { if (contains(itemId)) remove(itemId) else add(itemId) }
                ...
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            binding.deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
                   ...
            }

            // Activates last item, or item's clicked
            itemView.isActivated = activeHolder.contains(itemId)

            if(itemView.isActivated) {
                // Do anything you want by highlighted items.
            }

        }
    }
```

---

I hope this answer helped.

---

## UPDATE

### For perform click on last highlighted item:

inside onCreate() method of your activity:

```kotlin
lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                delay(300)
                recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(recyclerView.size-1)?.itemView?.performClick()
           }
}
```

Note: for repeatOnLifecycle() method you need `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0-alpha01` dependency.

Comment: Sure I'll try your suggested answer. but how we can perform auto click on recent added item in list which is highlighted ?

Comment: abstract all code inside the binding.layoutCar.setOnClickListener{} into a function and call the function inside the binding.layoutCar.setOnClickListener{} block and also inside inner onItemClick of EventHandler

Comment: so setOnClickListener will only call when we click on any item right but without user click I want to perform click action on last highlighted item. so how we can do it ??

Comment: By performClick() method on the itemView, Just updated the answer.

Comment: actually my subpage is in java class so I can't use coroutine. Why you use coroutine and delay for perform auto click ?